# Why does Vue's errorHandler fail to catch axios's error?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise, uncaught-exception

I set up a global errorHandler in Vue3's main.js:

```js
app.config.errorHandler = error => {
    console.log("catch error")
}
```

In general methods, it works well. For example:

```js
methods: {
  showMessage() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        reject("async error!")
      }, 500)
    })
  }
}
```

It print `catch error` in console, But when I use Axios to make a request, it can't catch axios's `Uncaught (in promise) Error`. Such as:

```js
methods: {
  showMessage() {
    this.$axios.get('/wrong-url/').then(response => {
      console.log('wrong url')
    })
  }
}
```

The global errorHandler cannot catch the error at this time. The console displays the error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404
```

I've googled it, but I can't find the reason.

Comment: best to use try-catch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The promise is not returned and isolated inside a method, which is a mistake. With a few exceptions, promise chain should always be preserved, this allows errors to be handled:

```
  showMessage() {
    return this.$axios.get('/wrong-url/').then(response => {
    ...
```

A fool-proof way is to use `async..await` because it forces a function to return a promise:

```
  async showMessage() {
    const response = await this.$axios.get('/wrong-url/');
    ...
```

It can be combined [linter rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/require-await) to avoid mistakes with promise chaining.

Comment: This is only for that individual request, best use an `interceptor` to handle all axios errors in the app. See my other response.

Answer (score 2):

`config.errorHandler` is for handling frontend errors. Yоu still have to create an `interceptor` when the app is created:

```js
...
created() {
    axios.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
        return response;
    }, function(error) {
        // Do something ...

        return Promise.reject(error);
    });
}
...
```

```js
app.config.errorHandler = (err, instance, info) => {
    // Do something ...
};
```